# What motivated formulation of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I'm late to the Hamilton-Jacobi equation party and would like to know more about the historical context of its origin. What motivated its construction/discovery? What were its affordances over other formulations of classical mechanics at that time? Did its formulation involve making or discarding key assumptions to attain such affordances, or do those affordances stem from the equation's formalism more than a theoretic advance?